# How to delete all Facebook posts/comments older than 1 year?

Tags: facebook

I love Facebook, but I don't want all my contacts to be able to sift through all my old posts.

So I'd like to delete all my posts and comments from Facebook after a defined time, like, say one year.

To do this by hand is tedious - is there any way to automatically delete all my Facebook posts older than a certain timespan from Facebook?

Comment: What do you mean Sam?

Comment: Today, on february 27th 2011 I want to delete all posts/comments older than february 27th 2010. And tomorrow I want to delete all posts older february 28th 2010. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new app available on Android that does this called Exfoliate. It exhaustively goes through all your friend's walls and deletes posts, comments, and likes.

Comment: That app seems to have been pulled from the Android market.

Comment: It is still available: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.worb.android.exfoliate but it Facebook doesn't authorize it on new devices, it cannot remove "timeline" posts, and old deleted posts somehow reappeared in the new timeline.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: none of these actually delete the content on other people's pages, they just make your page less cluttered and delete YOUR content. so, it will delete your wall posts, but it will not delete the commentary of yours on someone else's page, only clear the activity line stating that you commented on person's page. read the descriptions.

this does it: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/106969
it's just not automated clockwork, ie you have to each day/week/whatnot delete the stuff older than the selected post. i assume that is easily modifiable, especially if you run this script under a cronjob under linux.

this appears to clear/delete (as applicable) everything: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/106713

Comment: As far as I understand the script it does only delete those posts which are shown on the screen right now and older than the post I choose?

Answer (score 0):

- You could delete your account once per year and recreate it.
- You could build a Facebook app that deletes your posts possibly.  See the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for more information.

**UPDATE:** This [Self-Proclaimed Privacy Expert](http://www.cynthiaperla.com/facebook/460/how-to-delete-all-groups-and-wall-posts-from-facebook-using-imacros.html) claims to have written an iMacros script that will do what you are looking for.  I don't know if the free version of iMacros will do this though; you may need the paid version.

Comment: 1) if I delete my account once a year I'll not only delete the posts older than a year but more recent ones, too.

Comment: 2) I tried, but facebook apps are only allowed to delete posts they created themself (nasty, isn't it).

Comment: Sorry, that's all I've got :(.  You could maybe make a suggestion to the Facebook developers.  I'm not sure how hard that would be though.

Comment: Actually as far as I know it was possible for apps to delete all posts, but facebook closed this sometime last year, presumably because they don't want people to take control of their own data :(

Comment: Makes sense, the ability to delete data is contrary to what FB is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, this is exactly what I have been thinking for the past few months.  I actually want to delete ALL of my posts.  I am pretty sure you can accomplish this with imacros free.  O ff the top of my head, have imacros scan the page for the little x boxes (use firebug to grab the id and/or classes for the x's, and then have imacros click down and up, then repeat.